# Fabric js stickman - animate limbs programatically and maintain joints between all circles and lines

Tags: animation, html5-canvas, fabricjs

[image: Example of output]

I'm currently developing a stickman with Fabric Js, which will be programatically controlled. As per the Fabric stickman demo, you can drag and drop the circles. However, when you try to do this programmatically with more than one circle at a time, the joints break - where the lines no longer follow the circles positioning.

This is a segment of code, where I am looping through an object, to animate each limb.

```
let positionStateStore = {
    ARM_RAISE: {
        leftElbowCircle: {
            ref: 'leftElbowCircle',
            top: 152,
            left: 206
        },
        rightElbowCircle: {
            ref: 'rightElbowCircle',
            top: 158,
            left: 286
        },
        rightHandCircle: {
            ref: 'rightHandCircle',
            top: 110,
            left: 309
        },
        leftHandCircle: {
            ref: 'leftHandCircle',
            top: 111,
            left: 191
        }
    }
}

var _keys = ['leftElbowCircle', 'rightElbowCircle', 'rightHandCircle', 'leftHandCircle'];

for (var i = 0; i < _keys.length; i++) {
    var obj = positionStateStore.ARM_RAISE[_keys[i]];
    var ref = circles[_keys[i]];
    ref.animate('top', obj.top, {
        duration: 1000,
        onChange: function (){ animateObj(ref); },
        onComplete: function() {}
    });
}
```

Does anyone know how I can ensure that these remain in sync? Thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: Create a snippet/fiddle with your code

Comment: @Durga - thanks for offering to help - I managed to fix this issue and move my project forward. Please see: https://github.com/nicktaras/stick-person

Answer (score 0):

You try to achive something  like this?:

```js
(function() {
  var canvas = this.__canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
  fabric.Object.prototype.originX = fabric.Object.prototype.originY = 'center';

  function makeCircle(left, top, line1, line2, line3, line4) {
    var c = new fabric.Circle({
      left: left,
      top: top,
      strokeWidth: 5,
      radius: 12,
      fill: '#fff',
      stroke: '#666'
    });
    c.hasControls = c.hasBorders = false;

    c.line1 = line1;
    c.line2 = line2;
    c.line3 = line3;
    c.line4 = line4;

    return c;
  }

  function makeLine(coords) {
    return new fabric.Line(coords, {
      fill: 'red',
      stroke: 'red',
      strokeWidth: 5,
      selectable: false,
      evented: false,
    });
  }

  var line = makeLine([ 250, 125, 250, 175 ]),
      line2 = makeLine([ 250, 175, 250, 250 ]),
      line3 = makeLine([ 250, 250, 300, 350]),
      line4 = makeLine([ 250, 250, 200, 350]),
      line5 = makeLine([ 250, 175, 175, 225 ]),
      line6 = makeLine([ 250, 175, 325, 225 ]);

  canvas.add(line, line2, line3, line4, line5, line6);

  canvas.add(
    makeCircle(line.get('x1'), line.get('y1'), null, line),
    makeCircle(line.get('x2'), line.get('y2'), line, line2, line5, line6),
    makeCircle(line2.get('x2'), line2.get('y2'), line2, line3, line4),
    makeCircle(line3.get('x2'), line3.get('y2'), line3),
    makeCircle(line4.get('x2'), line4.get('y2'), line4),
    makeCircle(line5.get('x2'), line5.get('y2'), line5),
    makeCircle(line6.get('x2'), line6.get('y2'), line6)
  );

  canvas.on('object:moving', function(e) {
 
    var p = e.target;
    if(p.type == 'activeSelection'){
     for(i=0;i<p._objects.length;i++){
         p._objects[i].line1 && p._objects[i].line1.set({ 'x2': p.left+p._objects[i].left, 'y2': p.top+p._objects[i].top });
       p._objects[i].line2 && p._objects[i].line2.set({ 'x1': p.left+p._objects[i].left, 'y1': p.top +p._objects[i].top});
       p._objects[i].line3 && p._objects[i].line3.set({ 'x1': p.left+p._objects[i].left, 'y1': p.top +p._objects[i].top});
       p._objects[i].line4 && p._objects[i].line4.set({ 'x1': p.left+p._objects[i].left, 'y1': p.top +p._objects[i].top});
      }
    }else{
      p.line1 && p.line1.set({ 'x2': p.left, 'y2': p.top });
     p.line2 && p.line2.set({ 'x1': p.left, 'y1': p.top });
     p.line3 && p.line3.set({ 'x1': p.left, 'y1': p.top });
     p.line4 && p.line4.set({ 'x1': p.left, 'y1': p.top });
    }
    
    canvas.renderAll();
  });
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.4.6/fabric.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="500" height="600"></canvas>
```

Comment: Yep, this is what I started with and have built on top of this. It now works. I'll add the code soon - the trick was to update the lines inside the loop, as well as the circle positions.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking to create an animated stick person with Fabric please see the following link - which is being developed into a free alexa skill.

https://github.com/nicktaras/stick-person